# How does boolean here become false on its own

Tags: java, printing

*This is action listener of print button*

```
public void hookUpEvents() {
 print.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
      PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
      job.setPrintable( new Printer() );
      boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();  // boolean variable
       if( doPrint ) {
           try {
            job.print();
           }  catch( PrinterException exc) {
                System.out.println( exc );
              }
       }  else {
            System.out.println("You cancelled the print");
          } 
   }
});
```

}

When i compile this snippet along with whole code , **print button** gets displayed . The above is the action listener of the print button.

As i click the print button this dialog box is displayed :

[image]

Automatically after 3-4 seconds **You cancelled the print** is displayed on the cmd.
How does this happen ? And when i click cancel nothing is displayed.
How can the statement `job.printDialog();` return false on its own ?

[complete code](http://suhail03.my3gb.com/Printer.java)

```
// Program to print simple text on a Printer

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.*;


class Printer extends JPanel implements Printable  {

JButton print;

 Printer() {
  buildGUI();
  hookUpEvents();
}


public void buildGUI() {
  JFrame fr = new JFrame("Program to Print on a Printer");
  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  print = new JButton("Print");
  p.setBackground( Color.black );
  fr.add(p);
  p.add( print , BorderLayout.CENTER );
  this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension ( 300,200 ) );
  fr.pack();
  fr.setVisible( true );
```

}

```
public void hookUpEvents() {
 print.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
      PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
      job.setPrintable( Printer.this );
      boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();
//  PageFormat pf = job.pageDialog(job.defaultPage());
       if( doPrint ) {
           try {
            job.print();
           }  catch( PrinterException exc) {
                System.out.println( exc );
              }
       }  else {
            System.out.println("You cancelled the print");
          } 
   }
 });
 }

 public int print( Graphics g , PageFormat pf , int pageIndex) throws PrinterException{
   return PAGE_EXISTS;
 }

public static void main( String args[] ) {
   new Printer();
}
```

}

Comment: This works as expected when I compile and run it...

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth it displays the else statement if i don't do anything for half a minute

Comment: I do not get that behaviour when I run your code.

Comment: @ Oli but i get that behaviour

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth I don't have a real printer . Does that matter ? I am trying on a virtual printer

Comment: @ Oli yes with the exact code.

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth Let me tell you the similar behavior when using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame() , string )` in this also dialog box disappears after small duration.

Comment: If you are able to create a much simpler example that illustrates your issue, may I suggest that you edit your question to show the code directly?

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on your "Printer" class?  (Awkward name for a class, given that you might expect something named Printer to be representing an actual printer rather than something Printable.)

Comment: @ Charles Goodwin  ..and what should i tell you about the class ?

Answer (score 0):

Per the API, the print dialog is handled by the operating system, not the JVM, so I'm not completely surprised that different folks with different set ups could have different results. I suggest you try running it with an actual printer and see what happens.

Comment: Agreed.  However, in the comments, the OP says that he gets similar behaviour with a simple message dialog.  This leads me to believe that something pretty weird is going on here.